# Discord.py mute command error AttributeError

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My code is as follows:

```
#Mute Command
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    if ctx.message.author.server_permissions.administrator or ctx.message.author.id == '585578670207401984':
        role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name='Muted')
        await ctx.add_roles(member, role)
        await ctx.send("User {0} was muted by {1}!")
    else:
        await ctx.send("You do not have permission to mute this member.")
```

However, when I use the command, I get this error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'server_permissions'
```

Can someone help?

Comment: `server_permissions` has been renamed to [`guild_permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.guild_permissions) in the rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several mistakes, attribute errors in your code.

- `Member` object has no attribute `server_permissions` but it has [`guild_permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.guild_permissions).
- You can't compare member id with string, you need to compare with integer.
- `Member` object has no attribute `server` . You need to change `member.server.roles` to `member.guild.roles`.
- You can't add roles with `ctx.add_roles`, you need to do `member.add_roles`.
- At line `await ctx.send("User {0} was muted by {1}!")`, you didn't format the variables, so it'll just send `User {0} was muted by {1}!` to the chat. You can format it with doing `await ctx.send("User {0} was muted by {1}!".format(member.mention, message.author.mention))`.

You can change your code to:

```py
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.administrator or ctx.message.author.id == 585578670207401984:
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Muted')
        await member.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.send("User {0} was muted by {1}!".format(member.mention, message.author.mention))
    else:
        await ctx.send("You do not have permission to mute this member.")
```

Comment: Gives me this error:

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'message' is not defined

Comment: Change the `message.author.mention` to `ctx.author.mention` in string format line.